# how to make chrome pdf viewer faster

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

how to make chrome pdf viewer faster?
Is it possible to make it faster, or are there any chrome extensions that will serve as a pdf viewer which is faster than the default pdf viewer in chrome and adds more features to it.
I'm using fpdf to create pdf for the website that I am making. And the pdf that its producing is just text and tables without colors yet it takes more than 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or are there any chrome extensions that will serve as a pdf viewer which is faster than the default pdf viewer in chrome and adds more features to it

Disable the Chrome PDF extension and use the Adobe one.